# MATLAB - from mexa64 to mexmaci64?

Tags: linux, macos, matlab

In MATLAB, I have a MEX file ending with `.mexa64`. That is, it is for Linux 64-bit.

Now, I wish to call the function in my Mac MATLAB, which requires `.mexmaci64`. How may I do the conversion? Is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to get hold of the source file(s) and recompile the mex file

Comment: @Praetorian Exactly. Thanks. I have to go that route

Comment: @Praetorian I have added an answer. Do let me know if you are adding yours, in which case I will delete mine. :-)

Comment: No, your answer's good enough. Not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for balancing it back.

Comment: @SibbsGambling - I've upvoted your answer too.  This is the only way to get a MEX file that is compatible for Mac OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to do the conversion without recompilation.

Simply recompile the source code, e.g.,

```
mex sourceCode.c
```

It will automatically give you `sourceCode.mexmaci64`, if you are on OS X.